# Help Ubuntu 16.04 download java jdk/jre 6 manual installation , and set path in .bashrc?

Tags: 16.04, bashrc, support

[Problem of my Game that I want to launch did not work with java7-8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETUWo.png)

and solution that I need is 
[Solution because server only is supported with 1.6.0 JRE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLYjG.png)

I need to install it manualy but I don't know how exacly , and to set path in .bashrc
.If there is anyone who can help me out with this problem ,with live chat or somehow ,because I need to finish my server within 2 days. I will be thankful.

Comment: You can follow [this tutorial from Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-manually-install-oracle-java-on-a-debian-or-ubuntu-vps). It refers to JDK, but I must point that JDK also contains JRE embedded in it (folder /jdk1.8.nnnn/jre). If you prefer enable only JRE, you will do this: `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /opt/jdk/jdk.new.version/jre/bin/java 110` (e.g)

Comment: My host providers allready did install the jdk/jre 6 but in the path I think the jre bin it is not pointed ?

Comment: I suggest you do this: `update-alternatives --display java`, take note of java path and add this line: `export JAVA_HOME=<javapath>` to the end of `~/.bashrc` and `~/.profile` files.

Comment: java - auto mode
  link best version is /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/bin/java
  link currently points to /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/bin/java
  link java is /usr/bin/java
  slave java.1.gz is /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/bin/java - priority 1
  slave java.1.gz: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/man/man1/java.1.gz

Comment: JAVA_HOME=:"/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle"
export JAVA_HOME
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
Is this good as it is ? 
Althoug do I need to point to jre's bin ?
for example 
JAVA_HOME=:"/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle (                 ) " jre is in the same folder but need to point to jre's bin too ?

Comment: Type `java -version` to see if your default Java is JRE or JDK. If it's a JDK, so you can put `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/jre/bin/java`. If not, `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/bin/java`